# How to automatically bump version of peerDependencies for local packages in a monorepository with yarn worskpaces?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning, lerna

When running `lerna version` or `lerna publish` it bumps versions of all the packages in yarn workspace and do update relevant `devDependencies` but keeps unchanged versions in `peerDependencies` so packages reference old & incorrect versions and that breaks functionality.

**Example:**

Packages `A`, `B` & `C` where `B` & `C` depend on `A`. All have version `0.0.1`.
According to recommendations for yarn workspaces dependencies are pointing to exact version, like:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.1"
  },
```

Change `A`, modify `B` to reflect change in `A`.

Now if we run `lerna publish`  we'll get all 3 packages with version `0.0.2` but `B` & `C` keep referencing `A@0.0.1`. This breaks functionality of `B` as modification in `B` depends on change in `A` which exists only in `0.0.2`. So `package.json` of `B` starts to look like:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.2"
  },
```

while we would like it to look like:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "A": "0.0.2"
  },
```

When there is a lot of packages depending on A, or of there is an hierarchy of dependencies (e.g. `C` => [`A`,  {`B` => `A`})]  it's hard to impossible to update all of the dependencies manually.

**Probably it's by design:** (*but we need a way to solve this*)

- [Feature: allow updating peerDependencies in version command](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1575)
- [peerDependencies shouldn't be updated by `lerna publish`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1018)

So it seems Lerna is capable to analyse dependencies tree and update `devDependencies` but does not do that for `peerDependencies` intentionally.

But I'm struggling to find what is a recommended & right appoach here when we do need to update `peerDependencies` as well.

So, how do we tackle this?

**For reference:**

- Repository in question: https://github.com/angular-dnd/angular-dnd
- Issue: https://github.com/angular-dnd/angular-dnd/issues/4

Comment: Did you solve this? 

Comment: I've switched to https://nx.dev/ and https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate